# Modal box navigation left/right or up/down?

Tags: navigation, buttons, modal-view

On a site with a vertical scrolling layout where images are displayed one below the other, and clicking an image opens a Modal box to display it in a bigger view, navigation to the next and previous images should be left/right or up/down?

[image: Page layout]

[image: Left Right navigation]

[image: Up Down navigation]

In my experience it is common that pages use the left/right solution.

Why is left/right solution widely used rather than up/down which would respond to the actual display of the images in the page layout?

Answer (score 3):

The modal doesn't need to mimic the layout of the underlying page. Because it's more natural for people to read left-to-right in the western world. The pattern follows horizontal motion reading patterns.

Comment: Instinctively it looks natural. I guess my doubt is why it doesn't need to mimic the underlying layout?

Comment: Oh, wait, that's interesting. I misunderstood the original post. Now I would say it would be better to use the up and down arrows because it would follow the vertical scrolling motion.